# Как сделать фон кнопки input file?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="file">
    <input type="file" class="file-btn" name="file"  value="Выберите файл…" >
</div>

.file-btn  {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #000 url(../images/file.png) repeat-x;
    border: none;
    width: 110px;
    height: 19px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Как сделать фон кнопки инпут - файл?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://site-o-matic.net/?viewpost=19

В конце [ссылка](http://site-o-matic.net/content/buttons_example.zip) на архив с картинками и исходником css и html.
Имя же файла можно писать в каком угодно диве или инпуте.

HTML

```html
<div style="margin: 10px">
    <input type='button' value='Обзор' id='browse_button' />
    <input type='text' id='file_name' readonly=""/>
    <input type='file' id='file_browse' style='margin-left: -9999px'/>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
form {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

input[type="submit"], input[type="button"] {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 4px 28px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #408B98;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: Calibri, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
} input[type="submit"]:hover, input[type="button"]:hover {
    background-color: #36828F;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.400);
} input[type="submit"]:active, input[type="button"]:active {
    background: #23636E;
} input[type="text"] {
    width: 320px;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

JS

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#browse_button').click(function() {
        $('#file_browse').click().change(function() {
            var lastIndexOfSep = this.value.lastIndexOf('\\'); // Windows
            if (lastIndexOfSep == -1)
                lastIndexOfSep = this.value.lastIndexOf('/'); // Linux
            var fileName = this.value.substring(lastIndexOfSep + 1, this.length);
            $("#file_name").val(fileName);
        });
    });
});
```

[Пример на jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvXxj/)

Comment: Kremchik Вам плюсы. А как вызываем изменение стиля?

Comment: Приветствую! Думаю, это можно было бы написать в комментарий. Не очень понял, в чём вопрос?

Comment: @Kremchik Единственно, что вывести полный путь "на любом диве или инпуте" не получится. будет c:\fakepath\file.png... А так, +1

Comment: Ну да, имя файла, не путь. Только благородный IE показывает полный путь %) Firefox автоматически берёт только имя файла - собственно, большинству пользователей только оно и надо, так что тут проблемы нету.

Comment: Это считается уязвимостью, путь содержит много всего, что веб-сервису знать не положено.